# Minimum/Maximum Question (Calculus)

Tags: calculus

I have been solving questions about min/max & Lagrange methods.
Now I got stuck with this excercise without any clue of how to solve:
* Find the maximum of f(x,y) on the curve L:
$f(x,y) = \frac {1}{\sqrt{x+y}}$ ; L: xy=9 ; x>0, y>0

I have tried to find the f(x,$9/x$) but it didn't help me in any way.

the correct answer is: $f_{max} = f(3,3)$ = $(\frac {1}{\sqrt6})$

Appreciate a lot your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method of Lagrange multipliers to solve this problem. Consider the function:

$$g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}} + \lambda (xy-9)$$

Taking derivatives with respect to $x,y$ and $\lambda$ you get the following system of equations:

$$-\frac{1}{2} (x+y)^{-3/2} + \lambda y = 0$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} (x+y)^{-3/2} + \lambda x = 0$$

$$xy = 9$$

Substracting the second equation from the first one you get:

$$\lambda (x-y) = 0$$

The case $\lambda=0$ it's not possible because then $x+y=0$, so $\lambda \neq 0$ and you get:

$$ x=y$$
$$ xy =9 $$

Comment: thank you so much! this is the only way to solve such an exercise or there's something else?

Comment: You can also use the approach used in @Svetoslav answer, reducing the problem to finding the extrema of a function of a single variable.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, $f(x,y)$ is defined for $x+y>0$. Also you have $xy=9>0\Rightarrow x,y>0$. Then plugging $y=\frac{9}{x}$, as you did is OK - you get $f(x,\frac{9}{x})=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^2+9}}$. And the max of this function is really attained at $x=3\Rightarrow y=9/3=3$ and $f_{max}=f(3,3)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}$